# Property not updaated in Angular Component when reversing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have an Angular Component which has a public array variable initialized to `[]` . In the constructor I am getting a response from a service and updating the array using `this.variable = array.reverse()`. But this doesn't store the reversed array rather the original one. Anything I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```reverse``` is a method. So it should be like this: ```this.variable = array.reverse()```

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the description. I do use `array.reverse()`. Changing the reference works. Just wanted to know as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the reference to the array, so try

```
this.variable = [...array].reverse()
```

Comment: Yup. This works. Do we need to change the reference. Why does the reverse method not work directly?

Comment: `reverse()` does so in-place, meaning it just re-orders the items in the array, returning the original reference back. Angular CD only triggers when values change, and object-types are only "changed" when their reference changes

Comment: In most of modern frameworks, any reactive change will require a new reference, this reduces watchers, and improve performance (from framework point of view)

Comment: Thanks for making it comprehensive. Makes sense now :)